# Attempt to read property "num_rows" on bool

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, web, php7

Hola tengo un error en mi codigo que cada vez que voy a chekear el usuario me ese error y no se por que ya he probado varios metodos y inicializar una variable con el valor de num_rows pero tampoco, he probado a dejar el metodo estatico pero tampoco y ya no se me ocurre mas nada, adjunto mi codigo aqui para que lo podais ver, tambien he probado a crear otra base de datos pero nada, igual esta forma de conectarse la he sacado de los ejercicios de clase e incluso de videos por internet, tambien he probado lo de prepare statement y demas pero eso me terminaba dando mas problemas y llevo ya 3 dias que no doy con la tecla de como solucionarlo

```
class Conexion
{
    protected $servername = null;
    protected $database = null;
    protected $username = null;
    protected $password = null;
    protected $con = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->servername = "localhost";
        $this->database = "desatranques";
        $this->username = "root";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->con = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }

    public function insertarTablaTarea($id_operario, $nombre, $apellidos, $telefono, $descripcion, $email, $direccion, $poblacion, $codigoPostal, $provincia, $estado, $anotaciones_ANT)
    {
        $hoy = getdate();
        $fecha_actual = "" . $hoy['mday'] . "/" . $hoy['mon'] . "/" . $hoy['year'];
        switch ($provincia) {
            case 1:
                $provincia = "Huelva";
            case 2:
                $provincia = "Sevilla";
            case 3:
                $provincia = "Cordoba";
            case 4:
                $provincia = "Cadiz";
            case 5:
                $provincia = "Jaen";
            case 6:
                $provincia = "Malaga";
            case 7:
                $provincia = "Almeria";
            case 8:
                $provincia = "Granada";
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tareas`(`id_operario`, `nombre_contacto`, `apellidos_contacto`, `telefono`, `descripcion`, `email`, `direccion`, `poblacion`, `codigo_postal`, `provincia`, `estado`, `fecha_creacion`, `fecha_realizacion`, `anotaciones_ANT`, `anotaciones_POST`) VALUES ('" . $id_operario . "','" . $nombre . "','" . $apellidos . "','" . $telefono . "','" . $descripcion . "','" . $email . "','" . $direccion . "','" . $poblacion . "','" . $codigoPostal . "','" . $provincia . "','" . $estado . "','" . $fecha_actual . "','" . "- - -" . "','" . $anotaciones_ANT . "','" . "- - -" . "');";
        if ($this->con->connect_errno) {
            echo "fallo en la conexion";
        } else {
            echo "conexion exitosa!";
            $this->con->query($sql) or die("Error en algunos de los campos->>" . mysqli_error($this->con));
        }
    }
    public function getArrayRegistrosTablaTarea()
    {
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tareas";
        $registros = [];
        $resultado = $this->con->query($sql) or die("Error->>" . mysqli_error($this->con));
        if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                array_push($registros, $fila);
            }
        }
        return $registros;
    }
    public function checkUser($user_id, $pass) //si devuelve true significa que el usuario y la contraseña son correctas
    {
        if($this->con->connect_errno){
            return $this->con->connect_error;
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS encontrado FROM trabajadores WHERE id_trabajador='" . $user_id . "' AND contraseña='" . $pass . "';";
            $resultado = $this->con->query($sql);
            if ($resultado->num_rows == 1) {
                $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                if ($fila["encontrado"] == 1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desde esta funcion es de donde lo llamo

```
public function verTareas(){
        if(!$this->model->checkUser($_POST['usuario_inicio'],$_POST['pass'])){
            return $this->blade->render('login_error',['descripcion_error'=>'El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos prueba de nuevo']);
        }else{
            return $this->blade->render('tareas');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hazle un `var_dump();` a `$resultado` y dinos que obtienes

Comment: me ha salido esto  bool(false)  haciendo eso

Comment: probá con `if  ($resultado && $resultado->num_rows ...` la query retorna falso si hay algún error

Comment: si dejo de mostrarme el error, pero sigue sin funcionarme me devuelve falso despues de usuar como prueba un registro que existe y de probar la sentencia mysql en phpmyadmin a ver si es que estaba mal escrita pero no estaba bien escrita

Comment: probá imprimir el error de conexión onda `var_dump( mysqli_error( $this->con ) );` o como en `getArrayRegistrosTablaTarea()` que le pusiste un `or die( ...)`

Comment: podes ver un `var_dump( $sql )` a ver si llegan bien los datos, o pasar todo a pdo y consultas preparadas q suele ser mas limpio para depurar. aunque sospecho que es el nombre del field `contraseña` que habrá que ponerle backticks onda `\`contraseña\``

Comment: al final fue que contraseña por el encode que tenia no lo interpreteaba bien entonces he cambiado el nombre del campo y a pass y ha funcionado

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda estaba ya desesperado ^^